# InvalidEmailClass on imports?

Tags: marketing-cloud, import

We're trying to send emails to a small list of customers, but it keeps being sent to 0 records. To help figure out what might be happening we tried uploading the data into All Subscribers and we got the same error message for all the records:

**InvalidEmailClass**

[image]

Does anyone know what this error means??!

Comment: Did you ever discover what caused the error? I started seeing it today while attempting to import into a publication list in an automation.

Comment: If I recall, the issue here is that the EMAIL field was set to TEXT in the Data Extension and not EMAIL ADDRESS.

Comment: Salesforce support is looking into this for me. They initially suggested that the error was due to pushing a value other than "Yes" or "No" into the HTML Email attribute. But that wasn't the problem. Salesforce is still investigating the error. I'll post an update when I get one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article, it means Invalid update to the subscriber's "HTML email" status. The help page is only available in Japanese, open it in incognito mode and use translation

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323245&type=1

The solution for this is when importing to the all subscriber list, the HTML Email Column value must be "HTML" or "Text" although they look like a tickbox

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the HTML Email field type from Boolean to text and assigned HTML value on export.
It works! the subscribers have been imported into All Subscribers